# Insert values into mysql from the data stored in a file

Tags: mysql, file, insert

I have a database named `mydb`
There is table named `mytable`
the columns of the `mytable` are `"a","b","c","d"`
I want to insert the values into these `a,b,c,d` columns of `mytable` from a file `myfile.txt` which has data in the same order as that of the `mytable`.
Is there an easy way to insert values in to the table from the file without using any loop?

#### edited Part

The table already has large amount of data in it and I don't want to perturb it.
Instead of just loading data , I want to simply insert the values into the table and also I don't want to do it one by one but in one command without using a loop.

#

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try  LOAD DATA INFILE

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'data.txt' INTO TABLE tbl_name
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"'
  LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
```

## See [MYSQL Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html)

Answer (score 0):

You should use an MySQL Loader:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'C:/myfile.txt'
     INTO TABLE mytable
     FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
     LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [INFILE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html)

```
mysql -e "LOAD DATA INFILE 'ls.dat' INTO TABLE t1" db1
```

Answer (score 0):

It will be better if you use a csv file instead of a txt file. It will be beneficial if you want to edit the data in say openoffice or MS Office and then import it into the database. For MySql you can use "LOAD DATA INFILE" option. It fast and efficient, only prerequiste being that you should know the structure of the table.

Answer (score 0):

Save the file as a CSV (myfile.csv) file

Then issue the command

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'myfile.csv' 
INTO TABLE my_table 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
(Col1, Col2, Col2, Col4)
```

You may have to remove any blank cells that will be appended by the office program when you are converting to CSV format